# Why do i get error 139 in this matrice calculator?

Tags: c

This is a matrice calculator, it can mutiply and add two matrices.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int m, n, p, q, c, d, k,mult = 0, sum=0, sumles=0;
    char ch=0;
    char ch2=0;
    char ch3=0;
    char ch4=0;

    scanf("%d%d", &m, &n);
    ch = fgetc (stdin);
    int first[m][n];

    char operator;
    char opre=0;
    char oper=0;
    for (c = 0; c < m; c++)
    {
        for (d = 0; d < n; d++)
        {
            scanf("%d", &first[c][d]);
            ch2= fgetc (stdin);
            printf("CH2: %d\n",ch2);
 
            if(ch2!=32 && ch2!=10)
            {
                fprintf(stderr ,"Error: Chybny vstup!A");
                return 100;  
            }
        }
    }
  
    scanf("%c", &operator);
    printf("OPER %d \n", operator);
   
    scanf("%d%d", &p, &q);
    ch3 = fgetc (stdin);

    int multiply[m][q],second[p][q], sumtiply[p][q],sumlestiply[p][q];
 
    for (c = 0; c < p; c++)
    {
        for (d = 0; d < q; d++)
        {
            scanf("%d", &second[c][d]);
            ch4 = fgetc (stdin);
            printf("CH4: %d\n",ch4);
   
            if(ch4!=32 && ch4!=10 && ch4!=-1)
            {
                fprintf(stderr ,"Error: Chybny vstup!B");
                return 100;  
            }
        }
    }
    scanf("%c", &opre);
    printf("OPRE%d \n", opre);
   
    for (c = 0; c < m; c++)
    {
        for (d = 0; d < q; d++)
        {
            for (k = 0; k < p; k++)
            {
                mult =mult + first[c][k]*second[k][d];
            }
            multiply[c][d] =mult;
            mult = 0;
        }
    }

    for (c = 0; c < m; c++)
    {
        for (d = 0; d < q; d++)
        {
            sum =first[c][d]+second[c][d];
            sumtiply[c][d] =sum;
            sum = 0;
        }
    }
    for (c = 0; c < m; c++)
    {
        for (d = 0; d < q; d++)
        {
            sumles =first[c][d]-second[c][d];
            sumlestiply[c][d] =sumles;
            sumles = 0;
        }
    }

    //--------------------SWITCH------------------//
    switch(operator)
    {
         //+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++//
         case '+':
             if(m!=p || n!=q)
             {
                 fprintf(stderr ,"Error: Chybny vstup!C");
                 return 100;
             }
             //printf("P\n");
             //printf("Product of the matrices:\n");
 
             printf("%d %d\n", p,q);
 
             for (c = 0; c < m; c++)
             {
                 for (d = 0; d < q; d++)
                 {
                     printf("%d", sumtiply[c][d]);
                     if(d!=q-1)
                     {
                         printf(" ");
                     }
                 }
                 printf("\n");
             }
             break;
         //---------------------------------------------------------//
         case '-':
             if(m!=p || n!=q)
             {
                 fprintf(stderr ,"Error: Chybny vstup!D");
                 return 100;
             }
             //printf("M\n");
             // printf("Product of the matrices:\n");
     
             printf("%d %d\n", p,q);
             for (c = 0; c < m; c++)
             {
                 for (d = 0; d < q; d++)
                     printf("%d", sumlestiply[c][d]);
                 if(d!=q-1)
                 {
                     printf(" ");
                 }
                 printf("\n");
             }
             break;
     
         //*******************************************************//
         case '*':
              if (n != p)
              {
                  fprintf(stderr ,"Error: Chybny vstup!E");
                  return 100;
              }
              //printf("K\n");

              //  printf("Product of the matrices:\n");
              printf("%d %d\n",m,q );
              for (c = 0; c < m; c++)
              {
                  for (d = 0; d < q; d++)
                  {
                      printf("%d", multiply[c][d]);
                      if(d!=q-1)
                      {
                          printf(" ");
                      }
                  }
                  printf("\n");
              }
              break;

         // operator doesn't match any case constant +, -, *, /
         default:
             fprintf(stderr, "Error: Chybny vstup!F");
             return 100;
     }
     return 0;
}
```

The issue is this, If I input
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RT32X.png)

I get the error 139 and this messege: Segmentation fault (core dumped)
I read about this and it seems like my program is trying to acces resticted memory even though it shouldnt, at least I dont see how its able to even touch it. I think the problem mgith be in here  'scanf("%c", &operator);', because when I debuged the program, it didnt get past this, then again when this scanf gets the excess number, program should return 100 so I dont have a clue what is going on.

So if you can help it would be gladly appreciated, because I am starting to lose my mind and table.

Comment: Avoid constructs like `scanf("%d%d", &m, &n); ch = fgetc (stdin);`, I assume the `fgetc` is to consume a newline character. Don't do that, use `fgets` to read lines and then `sscanf` to parse values from that line. Also always check for the return values of any function call that reads input or parses it.

Comment: Why is your array `first[x][x]`? Shouldn't it be `first[m][n]`? Generally speaking, you seem to have overly complex array indexing. You should consider adding assertions on every single index before using it to ensure it is correct (within the correct range). There are probably numerous errors here that you will find quickly.

Comment: Your code is messy with many variable names that are very unclear. Restructure your code to use a couple of functions, because this is basically unreadable.

Comment: @jarmod I am new to 2D arrays so I didnt know how they work, this make ssense now tho, thx

Comment: @Cheatah yes its supposed to consume the new line and yes I will do that thank you

Comment: So, if your array is declared as `int arr[m][n];` and later you access an element in this array via  `arr[x][y]`, then you should consider adding asserts right before that access as follows: `assert(x < m); assert(y < n);` You could also assert on each index being >= 0 but that's a much rarer bug.

Comment: Sum can not be right : in k loop you do not use k, so sum[c][d] = p * (first[c][d]+second[c][d]). Same problem for sumlestiply.

Comment: If would be easier to make function for each operation. .

Comment: @PtitXav yea I copypasted forgot it was there thx.

Comment: sum[c,d] = first[c,d]+second[c,d] : no k loop necessary. Same for minus operation.

Comment: Can you explain the input you show ? Would be better to enter it as text.

Comment: 1 1 2\n 1\n +\n 1 1\n 1\n

Comment: How can you enter ‘1 1 2\n’ ? You should enter ‘1 1\n’ then ‘2\n’ . That is what ‘s coded : get size of first matrix, skip cr, then get values of matrix, then get operator.

Comment: I cant thats the problem I want my program to detect that the user has input wrong and shut itself down while returning code 100

Comment: Your indentation habits are .... nonexistent. Please confirn that `printf("%d", sumlestiply[c][d]);` is the only line you want inside the `for` you setup one line above. It is inconsistent with your other `case`s. Maybe not indenting has punished you....

Comment: If you try to debug code like this, clean up. Indentation is helpful. Checking return values of scanf is helpful. Initialising all variables is helpful. Init those which you think are written later anyway with special values you will recognise when they still appear. Fix your debug outputs, e.g. this `scanf("%c", &operator);
    printf("OPER %d \n", operator);` cannot really procude intuitively helpful info. In addtion to checking scanf return value also output everythign you scan, so that you can confirm your assumptions. Replace single-character-identifier by one-words, to help yourself...

Comment: @Yunnosch that was actually it, thanks it works now....

Comment: You mean what I found by indenting your code is actually the solution?

Comment: no nvm I accidently fixed it myself and thought you were right

Comment: But my code could break if soemone tried the "-" operant so I guess you helped a bit

Answer (score 0):

```
 ch5= fgetc (stdin);
    printf("CH5: %d\n",ch5);
```

by doing this right before return 0; this issue is fixed error 139 doesn't occur anymore

Comment: well the printf is excces but you get the point

Comment: Please explain why.

Comment: Wish I knew why this works

Comment: You can ask a separate question to get help with explaining.... Show the working code there, refer to this question (or copy the failing code), point out the small difference. Ask why it helps. Try however for a [mre]. I assume you can get rid of a lot of code. And please cleanup, it will get you potential answerers in a better mood.